# concise way to get names of list elements

Tags: r

I have a `list`, called `breakdown`, that partitions elements of a `vector` called `theNames`. I want another `vector`, with the same length as `theNames`, where each element of the new `vector` corresponds to a name of the `list`. In other words, if I have

```
breakdown <- list(first = c('a','b'), second = c('c','d'))
theNames <- c('a','b','c','d')
```

then what I want is `c('first','first','second','second')`.

The following works, but is not very concise. Is there a simpler way?

```
tmp <- sapply(theNames, function(name){ rapply(breakdown, function(elem) { name %in% elem })})
apply(tmp, 2, function(col) rownames(tmp)[col])
```

Edit:
I forgot to mention this: the order of the result should correspond with the order of `theNames`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach that doesn't assume that `theNames` is the same as `unlist(breakdown)`.

```r
map <- setNames(rep(names(breakdown), lengths(breakdown)), unlist(breakdown))
map[theNames]
```

```
       a        b        c        d 
 "first"  "first" "second" "second"
```

```r
map[rev(theNames)]
```

```
       d        c        b        a 
"second" "second"  "first"  "first"
```

```r
map[rep(theNames, 2L)]
```

```
       a        b        c        d        a        b        c        d 
 "first"  "first" "second" "second"  "first"  "first" "second" "second"
```

You can pass the result to `unname` if you don't want it to have names.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we have a named list of vectors, repeat each name the number of times given by lengths.

```
rep(names(breakdown), lengths(breakdown))
## [1] "first"  "first"  "second" "second"
```

### Added

An additional condition was added later that theNames may not be in the same order as breakdown.  Using b to stand for breakdown we have the following.  In this case it gives the same answer as above.

```
rep(names(b), lengths(b))[match(theNames, unlist(b))]
```

Comment: gahh yep that's slick. I apologize but I think I need to include more information. The order of this solution doesn't always match the order of `theNames`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try `stack`

```
> with(
+   stack(breakdown),
+   setNames(ind, values)
+ )
     a      b      c      d
 first  first second second
Levels: first second
```

Comment: this doesn't reference `theNames`

Comment: @Taylor See my update

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(tidyverse)

breakdown <- list(first = c('a','b'), second = c('c','d'))
theNames <- c('a','b','c','d')


theNames %>%
  map(function(nms) {
    map(breakdown, ~ if (any(nms == .)) nms)
  }) %>%
  map(compact) %>%
  unlist() %>%
  enframe()
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   name   value
#>   <chr>  <chr>
#> 1 first  a    
#> 2 first  b    
#> 3 second c    
#> 4 second d
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>